# Are the Narnia books and Harry Potter set in the same fictional universe?

Tags: harry-potter, the-chronicles-of-narnia

I've noticed many similarities for example:

- the lion symbol on the suits of armor looks exactly the same as Harry Potter's Gryffindor lion

  [image: Image comparing the two lions]
- there are 7 books in the Narnia and Harry Potter septuplegies
- the main characters are part Muggle or full Muggles

I'm sure there is more I haven't listed, But, is *Narnia* the same fictional universe as *Harry Potter* or a different universe entirely?

Comment: @closevoters: that's not POB. Either they're in the same universe or they aren't. The question is DVable at will for a couple of reasons, but is not opinion-based.

Comment: Why are we ignoring the possibility of Narnia being a time long long ago kind of situation like in Star Wars? The world was destroyed and HP universe occupied the current timeline.

Comment: The lion symbols are coats of arms.  The lions aren't identical, they are similar due to both being heraldic lions rampant.  If you Google "lion rampant" you can see pictures of lions rampant https://www.google.com/search?q=lion+rampant&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_5Y_9yqzgAhXGx1kKHaESB7EQ_AUIDigB&biw=1920&bih=938  and Lion (heraldry) can take you to pictures of the lion postures in heraldry  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lion_(heraldry)

Answer (score 19):

No. In the world of Narnia magic can be learned (and used in a haphazard fashion) by those without magical blood. In the world of Harry Potter, it's **exclusively used by humans with magical ancestry.**

> "I see," she said scornfully, "you are a Magician—of a sort. Stand up,
> dog, and don't sprawl there as if you were speaking to your equals.
> **How do you come to know Magic? You are not of royal blood, I'll
> swear."**
>
> "Well—ah—not perhaps in the strict sense," stammered Uncle Andrew.
> "Not exactly royal, Ma'am. The Ketterleys are, however, a very old
> family. An old Dorsetshire family, Ma'am."
>
> "Peace," said the Witch. "**I see what you are. You are a little,
> peddling Magician who works by rules and books. There is no real Magic
> in your blood and heart.** Your kind was made an end of in my world a
> thousand years ago. But here I shall allow you to be my servant."
>
> <sub><sup>[The Magician's Nephew - CHAPTER VI](https://gutenberg.ca/ebooks/lewiscs-magiciansnephew/lewiscs-magiciansnephew-00-h.html)</sup></sub>

That in itself indicates that these are not set in the same fictional universe.

---

With regard to the similarity of the lions, you should be aware that both the Narnia shields and the lion depicted on the Gryffindor banners are not original creations. They're representations of a [heraldic "Lion Rampant"](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/A_Complete_Guide_to_Heraldry/Chapter_11) which goes back to at least the 1400s (and before). Most depictions after the 1800s follow an extremely similar pattern to those seen in various fantasy books/films *including* Narnia and Harry Potter

> [image] 
>  <sub><sup>[Arms of Strange and Talbot - Catalogue of the Heraldic Exhibition in London, 1894.](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/A_Complete_Guide_to_Heraldry/Chapter_11)</sup></sub>

---

You might wish to note that JKR spoke on the key differences between the world of Harry Potter and Narnia

> I found myself thinking about the wardrobe route to Narnia [in the C.S.
> Lewis series including The Lion, The Witch And The Wardrobe] when
> Harry is told he has to hurl himself at a barrier in Kings Cross
> Station - it dissolves and he's on platform Nine and Three-Quarters,
> and there's the train for Hogwarts. **Narnia is literally a different
> world, whereas in the Harry books you go into a world within a world
> that you can see if you happen to belong.** A lot of the humour comes
> from collisions between the magic and the everyday worlds. Generally
> there isn't much humour in the Narnia books, although I adored them
> when I was a child. I got so caught up I didn't think C.S. Lewis was
> especially preachy. Reading them now I find that his subliminal
> message isn't very subliminal at all.
>
> Really, C.S. Lewis had very different objectives to mine. When I write, I
> don't intend to make a point or teach philosophy of life. A problem
> you run into with a series is how the characters grow up ... whether
> they're allowed to grow up. The characters in Enid Blyton's Famous
> Five books act in a prepubescent way right through the series. In the
> Narnia books the children are never allowed to grow up, even though
> they are growing older.
>
> <sub><sup>["The story behind the Potter legend:
> JK Rowling talks about how she created the Harry Potter books and the magic of Harry Potter's world,"](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2001/1001-sydney-renton.htm)</sup></sub>

Comment: In your illustration the arms of Strange have two lions passant while the arms of Talbot have one lion rampant.  It seems to me that you could have found a better illustration in which all the heraldic lions seen were lions rampant.

Answer (score 7):

## No.

The Harry Potter universe and the Narnia universe are separate universes.

There are many in and out of universe things to, so to speak, prove this, but I'll only list a few.

### In-universe.

- Harry Potter takes place entirely in our world, and the magical parts are "simply" hidden from the mundane parts. The Narnia Universe, however, involves travelling to other worlds/planes.
- There are no talking animals in the Harry Potter universe, while there are many of them in the Narnia Universe.

### And, more importantly, Out-of-universe:

- Had Harry Potter universe and the Narnia Universe been the same, either J.K. Rowling would be swimming in law suits or the Lewis estate would be swimming in (even more) money, or
- We would know about it. Unequivocally.

Comment: Babbity Rabbity is a talking animal

Comment: @Valorum Sure, but that's a character in a fairy tale within the universe, not a character in the universe.

Answer (score 3):

## No

To start with if anything was going to be in the other's universe *Harry Potter* would be in *Narnia*'s as *The Lion, the Witch and the Wardrobe* was originally published in 1950 and *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone* was originally published in 1997.

Even beyond that the "similarities" you've listed aren't really similar:

- the lion symbol on the suits of armor looks exactly the same as Harry Potters Gryffindor lion

  They're both just lions, there are only so many ways to depict them.
- there are 7 books in the Narnia and Harry Potter septuplegies

  I'm not sure how a book series having the same amount of books in any way dictates that the works are in the same universe.
- the main characters are part Muggle or full Muggles

  In *Harry Potter* sure and even then not really but in *Narnia* I don't think you can call them Muggles at all.

Answer (score 3):

**No**

First of all, IIRC Rowling never mentioned being inspired by Lewis. Moreover, *Narnia* universe was created something like 50 years prior to *Harry Potter* universe, so technically it would be other way round (but it's not really the case).

Also, all of the "similarities" you list seem to be coincidental or not a similarity at all.

There is also different underlying references throughout the series: while *Harry Potter's* arc with Voldemort and Death Eaters has a lot in common with Hitler and Nazi's view of the world, *Narnia* has more of a Christian theme.